# How to remove specific item from JSON object correctly in REACT js?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, state

In REACT JS, I have a **JSON object** in state component "**myrecords**" where items are grouped by their **Company** Names and it has following format:

```js
{
        "Master Automotives": [
            {
                "SparePartID": "43",
                "Name": "Oil and Lubricants",
                "Price": "4500",
                "VendorID": "48",
                "CompanyName": "Master Automotives",
                 "Qty": 1,
                 "TotalPrice": "4500"

            },
            {
                "SparePartID": "45",
                "Name": "Lights",
                "Price": "2300",
                "VendorID": "48",
                "CompanyName": "Master Automotives",
                 "Qty": 1,
                 "TotalPrice": "2300"
            }
        ],

        "Repair Solutions": [
            {
                "SparePartID": "47",
                "Name": "Steering Wheel",
                "Price": "1500",
                "VendorID": "60",
                "CompanyName": "Repair Solutions",
                 "Qty": 1,
                 "TotalPrice": "1500"
            }
        ],
        

         "FiveStar Automotives": [
            {
                "SparePartID": "51",
                "Name": "Brakes",
                "Price": "234",
                "VendorID": "70",
                "CompanyName": "FiveStar Automotives",
                 "Qty": 1,
                 "TotalPrice": "234"
            },
            {
                "SparePartID": "53",
                "Name": "Clutch",
                "Price": "999",
                "VendorID": "70",
                "CompanyName": "FiveStar Automotives",
                 "Qty": 1,
                 "TotalPrice": "999"
            },
              {
                "SparePartID": "55",
                "Name": "LED",
                "Price": "288",
                "VendorID": "70",
                "CompanyName": "FiveStar Automotives",
                 "Qty": 1,
                 "TotalPrice": "288"
            }
        ]
    
}
```

Im using this method to remove a specific item from **myrecords** state whenever delete button against an item is clicked:

```js
removeCartItem(CompanyName, sid,e)
{

  const items = {...this.state.myrecords};
  const j = items[CompanyName].findIndex(item => item.SparePartID === sid);

  items[CompanyName].splice([j], 1);

  this.setState({
     myrecords: items
   });
   
   }
```

Im sending **CompanyName**, SparePartID as **sid** in parameters of function to perform delete.

**It works Perfectly FINE and deletes the item on which I click.**

But **problem** is if a Company has only 1 item and I delete it, then still the **myreocords** JSON Object contains that Company with an empty array(no items). **Instead I wanted it to delete such a Company who has no Items left in it.**

SO that **myrecords** state should have only those **Companies** Data whose items are present.

Please help me to solve this Problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should to remove node if it have no items:

```
removeCartItem(CompanyName, sid,e) {

  const items = {...this.state.myrecords};
  const j = items[CompanyName].findIndex(item => item.SparePartID === sid);

  items[CompanyName].splice([j], 1);

  // rm company node if it have no items
  if (items[CompanyName].length === 0) {
    delete items[CompanyName]
  }

  this.setState({
     myrecords: items
   });

 }
```